# State not updating using setState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

setBlock is not updating block with the new values I submit to blockTitle and blockDuration (which are working btw).

```
export default function App() {
  const [blockTitle, setBlockTitle] = useState();
  const [blockDuration, setBlocksDuration] = useState();
  const [block, setBlock] = useState({title: '', duration: ''});
  const [blocksList, setBlocksList] = useState([{title: 'test', duration: '2h'}]);

  const handleAddBlock = () => {
    console.log(blockTitle);
    console.log(blockDuration);
    console.log(block);
    //setBlock({title: blockTitle, duration: blockDuration})
    setBlocksList([...blocksList, block]);
    console.log(block);
    //setBlockTitle('');
    //setBlocksDuration('');
    //setBlock();
  }
```

Here are the input components that update the state of the mentioned above variables:

```
<TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder={'Insert block title'} value={blockTitle} onChangeText={text => setBlockTitle(text)} />
<TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder={'Insert block duration'} value={blockDuration} onChangeText={duration => setBlocksDuration(duration)} />
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Here's the button to push to update to update the block:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={() => { setBlock({title: blockTitle, duration: blockDuration}); console.log(block); handleAddBlock(); }}>
```

I tried submitting default values (not based on those variables) but it's also not working. Tried also to do the setBlock elsewhere, in case it was a problem of asynchronicity. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure if I have understood you correctly. The console.log won't log your value right after you have set it since setState is async. Whatelse is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setBlocksList` is async and therefore you cannot see the updates immediately. To see the updated values move the console.log outside of `handleAddBlock`.

```
const handleAddBlock = () => {
   setBlocksList([...blocksList, block]);
};

console.log(blocksList);
```

[image: Edit React Native Web (forked)]